# How to associate an attribute option with a product

Tags: magento-1.7, product-attribute, custom-options

I would like to know how to add an option to a product.
I created the attribute via an sql file and it works.

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'score_attribute',  array(
    'group'             => 'General',
    'label'             => 'Score Attribute',
    'type'              => 'int',
    'input'             => 'select',
    'default'           => '0',
    'class'             => '',
    'backend'           => '',
    'frontend'          => '',
    'source'            => '',
    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => true,
    'user_defined'      => false,
    'searchable'        => false,
    'filterable'        => false,
    'comparable'        => false,
    'visible_on_front'  => false,
    'wysiwyg_enabled'   => false,
    'is_html_allowed_on_front'      => false,
    'visible_in_advanced_search'    => false,
    'filterable_in_search'          => false,
    'used_in_product_listing'       => true,
    'used_for_sort_by'              => true,
    'is_configurable'               => false,
    'used_for_promo_rules'          => true,
    'unique'                        => false,
    'note'                          => 'Product score' ));
```

Options are created dynamically. An option contains a score which can change, depends of a stock and several other things.
This option is correctly created and i can see it on EAV_Attribute_option_value.

```
 $attributeCode = 'score_attribute';
 $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')
      ->loadByCode('catalog_product', $attributeCode);
 $option['attribute_id'] = $attribute->getId();
 $option['values'] =  array($score);
 $installer->addAttributeOption($option);
```

But now i don't know how to associate it to a product. 
I tried to do this but nothing happens :

```
 $product->setData('score_attribute',$optionId); or 
 $product->setData('score_attribute', $score);
```

Could you help me please?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You can do that :

```
if ($product->getData('score_attribute') != $optionId) 
       $product->setData('score_attribute', $optionId)->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'score_attribute');
```

Good luck